# Implementing this design in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I know this might be far-fetched to ask, but does anyone know how to design a list like the one on Spotify's desktop app that displays the songs in a playlist when you select a playlist. In my project, I am getting my playlist data from Spotify's API and want to display the data in a browser using react native. I am not used to using react native on the web and its a little challenging than using plain react

This is how I would like it to look:

[image: Playlist tracks]

As you can see it has a header and what looks like a list item that gets highlighted when the mouse pointer is hovered over it.

This is another example, but it doesn't have a header

[image: another example]

I have tried to create the design, but I have terrible design skills. Btw these are all figma sketches

Answer (score -2):

Try material-UI. They have an amazing table component. Also, there's a ready-made component for all sorts of tables that has a bunch of cool functionalities: https://material-table.com/. After you get the functionality down then you can work on the design by using their JSS modules which is the best out there honestly.